# How to correctly store the data that retrieved from sever?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I defined   `var postImgData = [UIImage]()` at beginning of class to store all the images get from sever. The following is the code to get the image from sever

```
func loadPosts(){
    let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo:PFUser.current()!.username!) 
    query.skip = self.picArray.count // skip the already loaded images

    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

        if error == nil {

         if let objects  = objects{ 
            for object in objects{       
                self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.uuidArray.count, section: 0)
                    self.uuidArray.append(object.value(forKey: "uuid") as! String)
                    self.picArray.append(object.value(forKey: "pic") as! PFFile)
                    self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
                }, completion: nil)

            }
          }
        } else{
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
 }
```

Then i want to use `self.postImgData[indexPath.row] = UIImage(data: data!)!` to save each image data into `postImgData` array that defined earlier. But when i run the app it gives error said this line `self.postImgData[indexPath.row] = UIImage(data: data!)! Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range.` I am not sure why its happening? I tried use append function and its working but its didn't show the correct photo when i selected each cell. I am note sure what is correct way to do that? thanks

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return picArray.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //define cell

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! pictureCell

    picArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in

        if error == nil {
            cell.picImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)

           self.postImgData[indexPath.row] = UIImage(data: data!)!

        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Basically your postImgData array doesn't have the number of elements in it that your collectionView thinks it has number of cells. Looking at the code I can't understand the difference between postImgData and picArray which seems what you are appending to? Where do you actually insert elements into postImgData?

Comment: hi picArray is the array that receive the image data from sever then display these photos in the collectionview. And postImgData is the array that i want to store all the image data that retrieve from sever than if i click the certain collectionview cell it will use postImgData at this indexpath to load the image for another viewcontroller to display this photo. So how to fix this issues?